# iOS what is self.bound and CGRectMake() in Core Graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I was studying Core Graphics recently and always see some of the code assign `paperRect` in `CGRect` variable, so I search around in internet and I dunno what is `self.bound` and `CGRectMake()`.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of paperRect property is a rectangle that defines the size of paper chosen for the print job.

Please refer
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPrintPageRenderer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPrintPageRenderer/paperRect

Answer (score 0):

```
self.bound
```

is refers tha UI object rectangle/bound with respect to its superview.
whereas `CGRectMake` is the frame what you want to set for you UI object.
When you want to get `bounds` property of any UI object, you can say `self.view.bounds` & for `frame` `self.view.frame`.